# issue with parsing XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am currently having an issue with parsing my xml file, for some reason the .Value  of my where caluse is giving an error of:

'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Value'

```
var data =
     from lv1 in LoadedFile.Descendants()
           where lv1.Element("TEST").Attributes("id").Value == "1"
           select new { 
               Header = lv1.Attribute("type").Value,
               Children = lv1.Attribute("text").Value
   };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Value` property on a **single** Attribute not on on multiple attributes..

You should use `Attribute` instead of `Attributes`

So it should be

```
where lv1.Element("TEST").Attribute("id").Value == "1"
```